# How can I make dbUnit or hibernate stop subtracting an hour from my dates?

Tags: java, unit-testing, date, dbunit

So, I have an XML file I am using with dbUnit as a data source, and it has some dates in it.  The date in the file is like so: "2010-02-04", but once it gets loaded and I access it to print or compare in tests, it thinks the date is "2010-02-03 23:00".

I'm guessing this has to do with EDT/EST, but I'm not sure how I can force dbUnit (or possibly hibernate?) to use the correct timezone.

Does anyone have any experience with dbUnit and dates?

Thanks,
Peter

**EDIT**
Okay, I'm pretty sure, for some reason, it's reading the date in as EDT, which is correct, then storing it as EST, which is not technically correct (we are EDT here), but is correct per my computer which says it's EST.  This conversion is causing the date to "lose" an hour.  Not sure why Java thinks we are EST (Windows XP knows we're not), and am doubly unsure why dbUnit thinks the date should be EDT, since it, like Java, should probably be reading the incorrect timezone as EST.  This is pretty confusing.

**EDIT**
I took the Hibernate XML out because that's not the problem.  After more poking around, here is what is happening:
1. dbUnit reads the date as a String from the source XML and converts it to a java.sql.Date.  By nature, these do not store hours/minutes/seconds, but when you look at the millis, it's clearly adjusted by 4 hours worth in order to show that, though it's midnight here in EDT, it's 4am in UTC.  Also, this is backed by a Calendar, which has a timezone that is labeled "America/New York" or something equivalent.  I can't exactly remember.
2. Whenever I print this date, my system, which thinks it's EST reconverts 4am UTC to 11pm the previous day, which would be correct, except we're not in EST.
3. Whenever I create a date myself for testing as the example, since my JVM believe we're in EST, it adds ***five*** hours worth of millis to make the difference between it and UTC.  Clearly, these are different 'dates', and it fails.

So, the real question is, twofold, I guess:
1. Why does my console think it's EST?  My Windows XP settings are correct as far as I know.  I understand there used to be a problem in Java 1.4 that got the wrong TZ, but I think this has been since fixed and I am running (supposedly) 1.6.
2. Why does dbUnit, which is in the same JVM using the proper fancy TZ.

I suppose I could stop using dates all together, but I don't necessarily have that luxury.

Comment: To start with, why are you using a Timestamp column if you want to store a Date?

Comment: I'm not, I don't think. I'll have to double-check the schema. The intention is only to store & retrieve dates, which makes the whole "losing an hour" thing even weirder. But it's possible the field is identified somehow as a timetamp somewhere.

Comment: can you show the table structure. Can you also confirm how you checked what you have in the DB (with a SQL client? with JDBC?)?

Comment: We're using the functionality in dbUnit to create an in-memory database from the hibernate.  I've added the hibernate declaration above.  Right now it's a "date".

Comment: Okay, I removed the hibernate XML since it's not really the problem and it was very cluttery.

Answer (score 3):

5 years later, I hope I understand your problem correctly because you wrote quite a lot. Nevertheless I had a similar problem.

DbUnit or Hibernate switched my UTC times to my local time even though I had set `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` in my Spring application.
When I used `-Duser.timezone=EDT`, as [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831963/2021763) pointed out, my tests passed. Due to this I assumed that DbUnit fills its database before the actual application is started and therefore the default timezone is set too late.

To avoid this I came up with the two following workarounds for UTC, for ETC (or any other timezone) just switch it accordingly.

#### Regular application

*All* your test classes must set the default time zone. To not repeat my self I let all my test extend `UtcTimeZoneTest`.

```
public class UtcTimeZoneTest {
  static {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  }
}

public class TestClass extends UtcTimeZoneTest {
  // your tests
}
```

#### Spring application

In Spring applications you can also do the same thing, but I think the following is a bit nicer. Again *all* your test classes, must do this.  (Although I am not a Spring expert and I hope this has no drawbacks.)

```
public class UtcSpringJUnit4ClassRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {
  static {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  }

  public UtcSpringJUnit4ClassRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
    super(clazz);
  }
}

@RunWith(UtcSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
  // your tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing your tests?  Try adding the following VM argument to the command line (or however you're executing your tests):

```
-Duser.timezone=EDT
```

Comment: I have a feeling that would be a temporarily valid brute force solution, but it doesn't really work across our project.  I can't remind everyone who might ever run these tests that they should hard-code their timezone.  Plus, it might fail when we drop back into EST.